# limited spots for group items. different priority per group

Tags: discrete-optimization

Im not sure this is the right place to ask but it's a math problem so i think i'm at the right spot!

- list $L$ can hold $n$ items
- We have 3 groups $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$ each with their own $n$ items

List $L$ needs to be filled with the items from $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ but has limited space. So this means not all items can be in $L$. To distribute  the number of $n$ items equally over the groups I'm doing the following.

- L(25)
- g1(30)
- g2(10)
- g3(10)

summed $g$ items = 30 + 10 + 10 = 50
total $L$ space = 25
multiplier = 25/50 = 0.5

items from $g_1$ in $L$ 30*0.5 = 15
items from $g_2$ in $L$ 10*0.5 = 5
items from $g_3$ in $L$ 10*0.5 = 5
This makes a total of 25 items distributed equally over the groups

But now I want to make $g_1$ items more important than $g_2$ (and $g_3$) so that not 50% of the items are distributed but say 60% (in this case 30*0.6). This means $g_3$ and $g_3$ get les items distributed.

How can i accomplish this?

---

[EDIT]
So far i have:

```
/* 
* [Javascript]
* ni = total items in category
* n = total items to distribute
* qi = priority
* pi = percentage of items to get from category
* ci = calculated items to schow
*/

var n = 25;
var n1 = 30;
var n2 = 10;
var n3 = 10;

var q1 = 2;
var q2 = 1;
var q3 = 1;

// Solution with equal percentages
var pi = n / (n1 + n2 + n3);
// Solution with priority percentages
var p1 = (n * q1) / ((n1 * q1) + (n2 * q2) + (n3 * q3));
var p2 = (n * q2) / ((n1 * q1) + (n2 * q2) + (n3 * q3));
var p3 = (n * q3) / ((n1 * q1) + (n2 * q2) + (n3 * q3));

var c1 = n1 * p1;
//get the number of decimal places and add them to the next calculated items to schow
var c1decimalleft = c1 % 1;
c1 -= c1decimalleft;
var c2 = (n2 * p2) + c1decimalleft;
//get the number of decimal places and add them to the next calculated items to schow
var c2decimalleft = c2 % 1;
c2 -= c2decimalleft;
//use toFixed(0) to get an integer as sometimes c3 = ##.999999999
var c3 = ((n3 * p3) + c2decimalleft).toFixed(0);
```

wich gives

```
n : 25
n1: 30  
n2: 10  
n3: 10  

q1: 2  
q2: 1  
q3: 1  

pi: 0.5
p1: 0.625  
p2: 0.3125  
p3: 0.3125  

c1: 18  
c2: 3  
c3: 4
```

This is a right solution.
But when i change $n$ into 42 or higher i get this:

```
n: 42
n1: 30
n2: 10
n3: 10

q1: 2
q2: 1
q3: 1

pi: 0.84
p1: 1.05 << higher than 1
p2: 0.525
p3: 0.525

c1: 31 << Not possible
c2: 5
c3: 6
```

Comment: The meaning of *group* seems to bear no connection to what is called *group theory* in mathematics, and *distribution* similarly doesn't seem to refer to statistical distributions. I've thus removed the two tags, and re-tagged as discrete-optimization, since that seemed like the best-matching tag.

Comment: thank you, I didn't the best matching tag as i'm not familiar with english mathematic words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 3 sets of values $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$ with sizes $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$. You want to pick $n$ of them by picking $p_i$ percent of the values in $g_i$, for $i = 1\ldots3$. Your $p_i$ thus need to fulfill $$
p_1n_1 + p_2n_2 + p_3n_3 = n
$$
to guarantee that you'll pick $n$ elements overall.

Now, that equation obviously has lots of solutions, so you need *additional* requirements to have a unique solution. The requirement which produces your *first* solution is to require $p_1=p_2=p_3$. The solution is then $p_1=p_2=p_3=\frac{n}{n_1+n_2+n_3}$, as you have realized.

To extend this, you can assign a priority $q_i$ to each group, and require that $\frac{p_1}{q_1} = \frac{p_2}{q_2} = \frac{p_3}{q_3}$. In other words, you require that the percentages are the same *after* scaling them with the group's priority value. It follows that $p_2=p_1\frac{q_2}{q_1}$, $p_3=p_1\frac{q_3}{q_1}$ and thus $$
p_1\left(n_1 + n_2\frac{q_2}{q_1} + n_3\frac{q_3}{q_1}\right) = n
$$
which yields the solution $$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  p_1 &=& \frac{nq_1}{n_1q_1 + n_2q_3 + n_3q_3} \\
  p_2 &=& \frac{nq_2}{n_1q_1 + n_2q_3 + n_3q_3} \\
  p_3 &=& \frac{nq_3}{n_1q_1 + n_2q_3 + n_3q_3} 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

If you set all priorities to the same value, you get the same percentages as in your initial solution. If you, for example, set $q_1$ twice are large as $q_2$ and $q_3$, each element from $g_1$ will have twice the chance of being picked, since $p_1$ will be twice as large as $p_2$ and $p_3$.

Comment: Wauw, this looks awesome! I will get into this first thing tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: hmm its not quite right. If i set the priority **q1** higher than the **q2** and **q3**. The solutions gives me more **n1** items than **g1** can give.

Comment: hmm with a certain **n** value (higher than n1 and n2 and n3)
The p (percent) is higher than 1! Wich means i get a bigger size (at the n with highest priority) than is possible